# Вывод кода HTML, JS, CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать что бы по нажатию на кнопку выводился код ?
Допустим у меня есть блок и я его видоизменяю после этого я нажимаю на кнопку и мне показывается его код HTML, JS, CSS, но что бы он был не в строку а с переходами , пробелами.
Можете дать примеры , статьи или объяснить как то.
Буду благодарен

Comment: тег pre пробовали? http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre

Comment: Да , не подошло

Comment: чем именно не подошло?

Comment: Возможно вы не поняли суть вопроса надо сделать так что бы что написано в редакторе рендерилось 
как и сам условно div и его содержимое , так и код с тегами по типу когда на сайте нажимаешь посмотреть текст страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

только тебе придется писать отдельно код.
Допустим вот так:

```
let html код =`
    <div class="сontainer">
        <div></div>
    </div> 
`;
```

и выводить его вот так

```
<textarea
    onChange={(e) => htmlContainer(e.target.value)}
    ref={inputX}
    spellCheck="false"
    autoComplete="false"
    value={html код}
></textarea>
```

А так ты можешь сделать так, чтобы ты его изменял отдельно, создавать хуки на стили, если ты их изменяешь, выводить их в css под какой-то класс, а этот класс уже заранее написать в html.